# How can I tell IE to ignore ASP authentication redirects?

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer

If you try to access a page behind a logon page the system will kick you back to the logon screen.

How can I tell IE to ignore these redirects so I can capture the URL which the browser is attempting to access prior to the redirect?

Packet capture techniques aren't viable as it's using SSL and both the client and server are multiuser systems.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know that you can tell IE to do that, but a tool like [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/) would allow you to see exactly what requests are being made.

Comment: I've tried Fiddler but it's accessing the site via HTTPS so it doesn't give me any useful info.

Comment: Fiddler can decrypt https traffic. See [here](http://fiddler2.com/documentation/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/DecryptHTTPS).